# Trap signal SIGXFSZ not working when using ulimit -f

Tags: linux, bash, signals, ulimit, bash-trap

Trying to trap signal SIGXFSZ when applying ulimit -f in script
my attempts:

```
script:
#! /bin/bash
function catch_SIGXFSZ {
    echo "caught!!" 
}

echo running
ulimit -f 1

trap catch_SIGXFSZ 25

cat bigtmp.log > tmp.log

echo after
```

after running i get:

```
./try.sh
running
File size limit exceeded
after
```

any idea why the trap isn't working?
thanks for the help!